# Need to create Azure SQL Managed Instance from existing VNET and SUBENT using ARM

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

I need to create SQL Server Managed instance from existing VNET/SUBNET in ARM

But I tried multiple ways but its didnt help and getting failed again and again

So kindly help me to create script

Comment: Please add your best attempt so people can help you as you've asked.

Comment: Please find the my code with error details,Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/e2a3dc4e-989d-47c5-af8b-2855a9ee07bf/resourceGroups/POC-RG-TECH/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/test-sql-srv-01' at line '131' and column '9'. 'Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument